# Which is the difference between Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync() and Geolocation.GetLocationAsync() (MAUI Android)

Tags: maui

Which is the difference between Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync() and Geolocation.GetLocationAsync()?

I have tried both and I don't see the difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all can return the current location of the device. However, the `Geolocation.Default` provides the default implementation for static usage of this API:

```
public static Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.IGeolocation Default { get; }
```

That said, if you are using the `GetLocationAsync()` in **MAUI**, it's recommended to use `Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync()`.

For more information, you can refer to the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?tabs=android

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.sensors.geocoding.default?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: I don't know why it was downvote. I would like to know the reason because if it is a wrong answer, we could learn. That said, thanks for your answer.

Comment: De nada! Thanks for the response! I am glad to help if you have any other questions.